# How is JIT machine code laid out in memory in terms of jumping around?

Tags: memory, binary, compiler-construction, executable, jit

At a high level, a jump instruction moves to a specific place in memory. How does a JIT compilation system work in this regard exactly, at a high level? Does it store the entirety of the executable code in one contiguous connected chunk of memory, or is it scattered all over the memory according to some pattern (or no pattern)? How does the JIT system decide where to layout the new code in memory, and where does it place it relative to the previously existing code? Does it make any difference if the machine code is laid out contiguously or not?

Comment: The most probably is that the JIT system calls `malloc` or whatever its runtime uses to allocate memory. But that's going to vary from JIT system to JIT system, so it's hard to see how you would get a specific answer to this question without specifying which JIT compiler you're talking about. On the whole, memory is memory, so there's no particular reason why a JIT system needs to care where the compiled code is placed.

Comment: @rici Most likely it will be `mmap`, `VirtualAlloc` or whatever else way your platform offers to get a page for yourself. You're right that you don't really need to care about the address, but you do care that you can make the page containing the jitted code executable and read-only without affecting anything else, so it's important that the code isn't stored on the same page as anything else, which makes using `malloc` risky.

Comment: @sepp2k: In many environments (such as ECMAScript implementations) a JIT compiler may need to coordinate with the runtime's garbage collector. So it will likely use a higher-level interface. But you're right, it's probably eventually going to use the moral equivalent of `mmap`. Jitted pages do need to be executable, but I think they may or may not be read-only. Certainly, the page cannot be read-only while the JIT compiler is building the code, and jitted basic blocks will normally be a lot smaller than a page, I would think.